# Crowd and sonaqube doesn't work correctly

Tags: linux, session, centos, sonarqube, atlassian-crowd

I get these message when I start **sonarqube**.

```
 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: Crowd

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'application.name' : 'sonar'

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: application.login.url

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'session.tokenkey' : 'session.tokenkey'

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property:
 'session.lastvalidation' : 'session.lastvalidation'

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'session.validationinterval' : '1'

 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: cookie.domain

 INFO  web[o.s.p.c.CrowdRealm] Crowd configuration is valid, connection test successful.

 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
```

and **Sonarqube** start, but the users are only sonar and not crowd. 
I just suppress and reinstall crowd plugin.
Before that, it was run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar trouble while upgrading. If Crowd 1.0 is still compatible please use it.

If you are going to use new crowd plugin remember that the type of user (admin/generic) has to be configured on the crowd server and not sonar.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with the 1.0 plugin. Sonar does not start (crash).

Comment: I create a new application (**sonar2**) in CROWD, but I get the same problem with the same messages. Sonar find well the application with the URL (because if I forget 127.0.0.1 in the crowd addresses, sonar tells me and makes a crash). I don't know what I can do now.

Comment: Log the issue in Sonar's google group (as a last respite). If configuration was erroneous security realm started message won't appear, this is really strange. Can you also edit question to list all crowd related properties, ofcourse after masking url, username, password...

**users are only sonar and not crowd** with these do you mean tech users recorded in sonar.properties or users already in database